# Why does the node not inserted at the end?

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, insert, sortedlist

After I compile the code, there is no output at all.
Why is the value 10 not inserted at the end of the linked list? 
I thought that after `p == NULL`, the while loop is exited, `j->next` would be `NULL` as well. So, the temp node will be inserted at the end of the linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void Create(int array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    struct Node *temp, *last;
    first = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    first->data = array[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    last = first;
    
    for (i = 1 ; i < size ; i++){
        temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp->data = array[i];
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void Print(struct Node *p)
{
    while(p != NULL){
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void InsertingInSortedList(struct Node *p, int value)
{
    struct Node *temp , *j = NULL;
    temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = value ;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(p == NULL){
        first = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while(p->data < value && p){
            j = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        temp->next = j->next;
        j->next = temp;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int b[] = {1,3,5,7,8,9};
    int num = 6;
    Create(b,num);

    InsertingInSortedList(first, 10);
    Print(first);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void Create(int array[], int size)` <<-- why does this function return `void`? It is more natural to return (a pointer to) the created list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `p->data < value && p` is wrong. You need to check if `p` is NULL *before* you dereference `p`.

The correct condition is `p && p->data < value`.

Google *c short circuit evaluation* for more information.

Comment: Useful, but there are other problems in the original code. It does not handle insertion to the front of a non-empty list.